# Access Web Inspector in Safari with AppleScript

Tags: safari, applescript, web-inspector

I'm trying to create an AppleScript script which essentially downloads files from Safari. However, the files are not available for download via the web page, so I usually open up the `Web Inspector` and then go to `Resources` and then in a folder called `Other`, download the file.

I've been searching the web for a method to do this via AppleScript, but to no avail. My question is therefore: How can I access the Web Inspector > Resources > Other files in my current Safari window? I [know](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/WebInspector) that it is possible to bring up the Web Inspect using <kbd>⌥⌘I</kbd>, and then you can change pane inside of the Inspector using <kbd>⌘]</kbd>. But I can't get focus on the list of Resources Files, as shown below:

[image]

Is it possible to access this `.mp3` file inside of the `Other` folder without using shortcut commands? And if not/if so, how can I access the `Other` folder inside of this window pane?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you can access the .mp3 file some other way? Rather than using the Web Inspector, perhaps you can find the link to the .mp3 file within the page source code, and then download it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the "Other" folder, then you will have to copy the web address you need it for, reset safari, go to the web page via the html bar and then open up the web inspector via alt>cmd>I and it should be there.Not sure what Apple Script has to do with anything (But I have never used it :P)
Hope this helps